# Apache Beam Python SDK - support for withAllowedLateness in Python

Tags: python, sdk, apache-beam

When will support be added for withAllowedLateness in the Python SDK? are there any known work-arounds? We need to support late data but have all code written in Python. We don't want to switch to use Java just for this item, but need support. Ideas?

Here is the official lack of support for this:
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#watermarks-and-late-data

"7.4.1. Managing late data
Note: Managing late data is not supported in the Beam SDK for Python."

Answer (score 0):

Its in progress. You can track https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8824 for updates.